# Can able to login to a local website from another machine

Tags: dns, login, localhost, file-server

i installed a local website called FileCloud on my ubuntu_22.04.
The website can be accessible with http://127.0.0.1 , http://localhost and http://10.0.2.2
which could be my machine's ip.

From http://127.0.0.1 and http://localhost , I can able to login as admin into my website.

But with http://10.0.2.2, I can't able to login, the site just buffers forever.

Even when i tried with diffrent devices, the results are always same.

I'll attach an image for better clarifications.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wQ0A.png)

Comment: If you are able to access the service on localhost and 127.0.0.1, but not other IP addresses, then this could be either a routing issue, or a firewall issue. Depending on the application, it could also be an application issue. Your screenshot shows a 192.168.x.x address, with content loaded, which would lead me to believe the application is expecting specific hostnames and cannot handle the 192.168.x.x address.

Comment: You should explain this contradiction between the IP addresses you list and the image.

Comment: Looking at your image some resources are loaded. (1) Check if these resources come from a cache. — Reload the Firefox tab by pressing the key-combination `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`R` // (2) If these resources are not from the cache the DNS and firewall should not be the problem. To find the resource firefox is waiting for, have a look in the "Error Log" at the "Developer Tools" of Firefox. — Please extend your question by these info.